# How to get value from other table to integrate into subquery?

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, join, subquery

I had table A as follows:

```
 ID | NegeriID  | yeartamatkhidmat | yeartamatkhidmat
-----------------------------------------------------------------
 1  |     2     |      2001        |      2002
 1  |     2     |      2003        |      2007
 2  |     2     |      2008        |      2012
 2  |     1     |      2013        |      2018
 3  |     3     |      2000        |      2001
```

I had a subquery to get the sum of years of working experience according to Negeri(state) as follows:

```
 $query = DB::table('B')
                ->select('B.name','B.ID', '');


 $query->select(DB::raw('B.name, m.NegeriID, sum(distinct m.duration)'))
                  ->from(DB::raw('(SELECT ID, NegeriID, yeartamatkhidmat - yearmulakhidmat as duration FROM A) AS m 
                    RIGHT JOIN B ON B.ID=m.ID'))
                  ->groupBy('m.ID', 'm.NegeriID');
```

I had another table with the value of name and Negeri:

Table B

```
    ID |  Name 
    --------------
    1  |  Bill   
    2  |  Jane   
    3  |  Roy
```

Table C

```
   NegeriID |  Negeri 
    --------------
       1    |    E  
       2    |    F  
       3    |    G
```

How to take value of name and Negeri from the tables to integrate into the subquery above?

I had tried this code:

```
 $query->JOIN(DB::RAW('(SELECT m.itemRegistrationID, m.NegeriID, sum(distinct m.duration) AS s 
                                        FROM (SELECT itemRegistrationID, NegeriID, yeartamatkhidmat - yearmulakhidmat as duration FROM itemregistrationpangkat) AS m)'),
                                      function($join){
                                        $join->on("itemregistrations.itemRegistrationID","=","m.itemRegistrationID");
                                      })
                  ->groupBy('m.itemRegistrationID', 'm.NegeriID');
```

But it shows error:

```
    Syntax error or access violation: 1248 Every derived table must have its own alias
```

Comment: The answer is that you join to these other tables.  But, I can't venture an answer, because your query/Laravel code is too complex.

Comment: Yes, I tried to join with righ join but it appears error "Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'dbhre1m_v2_migrate.itemregistrations.ItemRegistrationID' isn't in GROUP BY "

Comment: I had simplified the query to related question.